# Next JS- How to construct layout correctly

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next.js13

I have created 2 footer and header components that I want to include in my nextjs layout, this configuration works for me on all pages except the default page or home (page.tsx).
It only gives me an error with this file, the rest of the pages load fine

Header Component
**Header Component**

```
"use client";
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import DynamicTitle from './DynamicTitle';
import Link from "next/link";


const Header = () => {
    const [isDropdownOpen, setDropdownOpen] = useState(false);

    const toggleDropdown = () => {
        setDropdownOpen(!isDropdownOpen);
    };

    const currentPath = typeof window !== 'undefined' ? window.location.pathname : '/';

    return (
        <>
            <DynamicTitle />
            <header className="bg-gray-800 text-white py-4">
                <nav className="flex justify-center space-x-4">
                    <div className="flex justify-between items-center">
                        <div className="flex space-x-4">
                            <Link href="/">Inicio</Link>

                            <div className="relative">
                                <button
                                    onClick={toggleDropdown}
                                    className={`hover:text-gray-300 focus:outline-none ${isDropdownOpen ? 'text-blue-500' : 'text-white'} px-3 py-2 rounded`}
                                >
                                    Guías
                                    <svg
                                        className="w-4 h-4 inline ml-1 transform transition-transform duration-300"
                                        fill="none"
                                        stroke="currentColor"
                                        viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                                        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                                        style={{
                                            transform: isDropdownOpen ? 'rotate(180deg)' : 'rotate(0deg)',
                                        }}
                                    >
                                        <path
                                            strokeLinecap="round"
                                            strokeLinejoin="round"
                                            strokeWidth="2"
                                            d="M4 6h16M4 12h16m-7 6h7"
                                        />
                                    </svg>
                                </button>
                                {isDropdownOpen && (
                                    <div className="absolute right-0 mt-2 bg-gray-800 text-white p-2 space-y-2 min-w-min min-w-max">
                                        <button
                                            onClick={() => window.location.href = '#'}
                                            className="block hover:bg-gray-700 rounded px-2 py-1 custom-min-width text-white"
                                        >
                                            Guía 1
                                        </button>
                                    </div>
                                )}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </nav>
            </header>
        </>
    );
};

export default Header;
```

The layout file has this structure.

```
import React from 'react';
import './globals.css';
import Header from "@/app/components/template/Header";
import Footer from "@/app/components/template/Footer";

export default function RootLayout({ children }: {
    children: React.ReactNode;
}) {
    return (
        <html lang="en">
            <Header/>
                <body>
                    {children}
                </body>
            <Footer/>
        </html>
    );
}
```

Page.tsx file

```
"use client";

// Home.js
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import RootLayout from "@/app/layout";
import LastCars from "@/app/components/LastCars";

export default function Home() {

    const [apiResult, setApiResult] = useState<{ kwneed: number, cost: number } | null>(null);
    const [switchError, setSwitchError] = useState(false);

    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
    };


    return (
        <RootLayout>

                <div className="flex w-full text-justify flex-col py-10">

                    <p>
                        text
                    </p>
                </div>


                <form className="space-y-4 flex">
         //
                </form>

                <HomeContent/>
                <LastCars />
        </RootLayout>
    );

}
```

Error received

```
app-index.js:31 Warning: Expected server HTML to contain a matching <header> in <html>.
    at header
    at Header (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./app/components/template/Header.js:18:94)
    at html
    at RedirectErrorBoundary (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/redirect-boundary.js:73:9)
    at RedirectBoundary (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/redirect-boundary.js:81:11)
    at NotFoundErrorBoundary (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/not-found-boundary.js:54:9)
    at NotFoundBoundary (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/not-found-boundary.js:62:11)
    at DevRootNotFoundBoundary (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/dev-root-not-found-boundary.js:32:11)
    at ReactDevOverlay (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/react-dev-overlay/internal/ReactDevOverlay.js:66:9)
    at HotReload (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/react-dev-overlay/hot-reloader-client.js:326:11)
    at Router (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/app-router.js:148:11)
    at ErrorBoundaryHandler (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/error-boundary.js:77:9)
    at ErrorBoundary (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/error-boundary.js:104:11)
    at AppRouter (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/app-router.js:396:13)
    at ServerRoot (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/app-index.js:166:11)
    at RSCComponent
    at ReactDevOverlay (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/react-dev-overlay/internal/ReactDevOverlay.js:66:9)
    at Root (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/app-index.js:183:11)

react-dom.development.js:6789 Uncaught Error: Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server.
    at throwOnHydrationMismatch (webpack-internal:///(:3000/app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:6789:9)
    at tryToClaimNextHydratableInstance (webpack-internal:///(:3000/app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:6834:7)
    at updateHostComponent$1 (webpack-internal:///(:3000/app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:15520:5)
    at beginWork$1 (webpack-internal:///(:3000/app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:17355:14)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (webpack-internal:///(:3000/app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:19443:14)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackImpl (webpack-internal:///(:3000/app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:19492:16)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (webpack-internal:///(:3000/app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:19567:29)
    at beginWork (webpack-internal:///(:3000/app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:25711:7)
    at performUnitOfWork (webpack-internal:///(:3000/app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:24540:12)
    at workLoopConcurrent (webpack-internal:///(:3000/app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:24526:5)
    at renderRootConcurrent (webpack-internal:///(:3000/app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:24482:9)
    at performConcurrentWorkOnRoot (webpack-internal:///(:3000/app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:23339:38)
    at workLoop (webpack-internal:///(:3000/app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/scheduler/cjs/scheduler.development.js:261:34)
    at flushWork (webpack-internal:///(:3000/app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/scheduler/cjs/scheduler.development.js:230:14)
    at MessagePort.performWorkUntilDeadline (webpack-internal:///(:3000/app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/scheduler/cjs/scheduler.development.js:537:21)
```

I have been looking at the documentation of nextjs, stackoverflow but without success. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you also provide your header component. Since the error states `Expected server HTML to contain a matching <header> in <html>`. It'd be nice to see it. Also `HomeContent` is missing in the `page.tsx` file.

Comment: @moritzgvt code added, thxs